# How to embed wave dashboard in external web sites

Tags: einstein-analytics

below is vf page where i tried to access wave dashboard along with accesstoken and endpoint url.

    
    Sample Dashboard

```
<div id="lightning" />

<script>
    $Lightning.use("wave:waveApp", function() {               
         $Lightning.createComponent("wave:waveDashboard", {                    
             dashboardId: "0FK7F000000H7K8WAK"                
         }, "app");
        }, "https://lt-wave-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/analytics/wave/wave.apexp?tsid=02u7F000000tvPn", "00D7F000000pXMH!AR8AQO.bcc44cTOYSFnr5EnbO5VHKOLk2.pRtvB95GtatxSw6h8Lt1fsn5yFIEREkkfREgjLMP.NBVsgm8sBWcmtWmrJ_SDy")
</script>
```

i am getting blank page with only header.

Answer (score 1):

I spent quite a bit of time on this. The first step you have to do is to go through the below video by Mohit

https://www.salesforce.com/video/304563/

I went through it and post going through that this is my feedback

I am not sure whether there is a pre-built wave component wave:waveApp and wave:waveDashboard exists in the instance as documented here by Salesforce

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_bi_lightning_out.htm

You can type anything there and it doesn't display anything meaning, the component doesn't exist.

One way is to find out from Salesforce where to get the component to reference it or

Alternatively as detailed in Mohith video create a custom Lightning component that uses that uses the standard embedding technology of a wave dashboard as detailed here and do a lightning call out of the custom Lightning component from an external web page or another Salesforce instance.

You can explore in similar lines. Hope it helps!